# How to get an image from a tweet using tweepy

Tags: twitter, tweepy

If I look at [this tweet](https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1275955989322162177), I can see that images are clearly attached. Yet I get the following:

```
>>> status = api.get_status(1275955989322162177, include_entities = True)
>>> status.entities
{'hashtags': [], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [], 'urls': [{'url': 'https:///Ofq2EYjEPA', 'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1275955989322162177', 'display_url': 'twitter.com/i/web/status/1…', 'indices': [116, 139]}]}
```

As you can see, there are no images. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to use the following flag:

```
status = api.get_status(1275955989322162177, include_entities = True, tweet_mode='extended')
```